# can anyone consume this service?

Tags: .net, wcf

This is my service. Any other better way to design this? can any one consume this service i.e. javascript,php, Java.

Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    datas GetData(input ip);      
}
[CollectionDataContract]
public class datas : List<output>
{
    public datas() { }
    public datas(List<output> datas) : base(datas) { }
}
[DataContract]
public class output
{ 
    [DataMember]
    public string city
    {
        get;
        set;
    }      
}
[DataContract]
public class input
{
[DataMember]
    public string id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   
}
```

service implementation

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public datas  GetData(input ip)
    {            
           datas collection = new datas();                             
           tbTemp = con.GetDataTable(query);                          
           foreach (DataRow dtRow in tbTemp.Rows)
           {
               output op = new output();
               op.city = dtRow[0].ToString();                  
               collection.Add(op);
           }               
           return collection;           
    }      
}
```

i'm using "webHttpBinding" binding. or should i go for WCF RESTful service and like that?

Answer (score 2):

Implementing of the service should be based on your intentions.

If you're going to create service over HTTP I would recommend you to use ASP.NET MVC Web API.

Review this [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2012/03/05/wcf-or-asp-net-web-apis-my-two-cents-on-the-subject.aspx). It will clarify some points and help you with the choice.